# How do I get a detailed decision tree when 7 of my 13 independent variables are categorical in nature?

Tags: r, decision-tree

I'm analyzing persistency using decision trees with 13 independent variables (7 of which are categorical) but I'm getting a tree considering only one numeric variable).

My code is:

```
fmla=STATUS~.

tm=rpart(fmla, data=trainData,method = "class")
```

[image]

Comment: Possibly the other independent variables are not sufficiently informative about the response so that no further splitting occurs. It's hard to say more based on the information provided. Also, the image you posted has not been generated with the code in your question. Hence I would recommend embellishing the question with more details and a reproducible example.

Comment: my target variable is categorical with values of 'persistent or non persistent' and the independent variables are : {subchannel,region,product_name,product_type,frequency,premium_type[categorical]} and {term,ppt,afyp,premium_due,premium_due_amount[numeric]}              everytime i try to build a tree its only taking one numeric variable

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because information gained obtained by splitting of the tree is less than the default threshold.

Rpart provides ways to control how a tree is built.The following are some controls that you can play with :

1. Rpart stops the tree splitting, if the information gained is less than 0.01(default).This information gain/rmse gain/gini gain is specified by the parameter "cp" in rpart controls.
2. parms options is used to indicate the splitting function.
3. rpart.controls is used to indicate tree parameters.
4. Most used options of rpart.controls are  max depth ( tree depth ), minbucket  (min. number of observations in each node ) and minsplit( the min. number of observations required in a node before splitting further. )

Pls note : By default when the method="class", the rpart classification tree uses gini index for node split criterion.

Example of customised rpart tree:

```
      rpart(data=traindata, 
      formula = Status ~ .,
      method = "class",
      parms=list(split="information"),
      control=rpart.control(minbucket=50,minsplit=100, cp=0.0000001, maxdepth=30))
```

Comment: Thanks I ran the code and I'm getting this Error: unexpected ')' in "control=rpart.control(minbucket=50,minsplit=minspl, cp=0.0000001, maxdepth=30))"

Comment: It should run now. I think its was failing because of uninitiailized variable in minsplit control.